# Unable to contact my own server

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the following setup:

- Ros indigo
- -Laptop hosting a local wifi hotspot with IP 10.42.0.1. It is also
  connected to the internet via
  ethernet, but on a different network
  interface, so different (and
  unrelated IP).
- -Youbot that has joined the created hotspot (These are the only two
  things in that network). IP
  10.42.0.20
- -SSH 'd into the Youbot on the mentioned Laptop.
- The .bashrc on the laptop has the
  following lines in it:

  ```
   export ROS_IP=10.42.0.1
   export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311
  ```
- The youbot sources the .bashrc on ssh
  login and it also contains

  ```
   export  ROS_IP=10.42.0.1 
   export  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311
  ```

What I can do:

- ping in either direction (always
  using the IP, never the hostname)
- Netcat in either direction
- Start roscore on the Laptop

What I cannot do:

- Start the youbot driver on the
  youbot. It always terminates with the
  "Unable to contact my own server at
  [http://10.42.0.1:35449/]" message. I feel like I've looked
  at a lot of tutorials and don't see
  what's wrong, but there obviously is
  something wrong. Can anybody tell me
  what please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236912/unable-to-contact-my-own-server/) by [RunOrVeith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27171/runorveith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> - Youbot that has joined the created hotspot (These are the only two
>   things in that network). IP 10.42.0.20

> ...

> The youbot sources the .bashrc on ssh login and it also contains

> ```
> export  ROS_IP=10.42.0.1
> ```

If this is not a typo, then that is your problem. You state that the youbot is at `10.42.0.20`, but you set its `ROS_IP` to `10.42.0.1`. That cannot work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RunOrVeith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27171/runorveith/) on 2016-06-14**:
Thanks, I thought ROS_IP was also supposed to be the IP that hosts roscore, but now that you mention it that doesn't really make sense!